# Ideal in polynomial rings: When changing the basis, can we bound the degree of coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

I came across the following problem.
It seems reasonable at first sight, but still I’m not entirely sure whether it is correct or not.
Maybe you have a fun time solving it or finding a counterexample.

**Setting.**
We work in a multivariate polynomial ring $K[X] = K[X_1,\dotsc,X_N]$ in $N \in \mathbb{N}^+$ variables over a field $K$.
Let an ideal $I = (f_1, \dotsc, f_m) = (g_1, \dotsc, g_n) \subseteq K[X]$ given by two different bases.
Being two bases of the same ideal, we can obviously express each $g_i$ as a combination of the $f_j$ and vice versa.
Suppose that in one direction we have $g_i = \sum_{j=1}^m s_{ij}f_j$ with coefficients $s_{ij} \in K[X]$ of degree at most $d = \max_{i,j} \deg(s_{ij})$.

Now I am interested in the other direction.
We know that there exists a representation $f_j = \sum_{i=1}^n t_{ji}g_i$ with $t_{ji} \in K[X]$.

**Question.** Is there a bound $\beta = \beta(N,\max_j \deg(f_j),\max_i \deg(g_i),d) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t_{ji}$ can be chosen to be of degree at most $\beta$?

*Loosely speaking: If we know how one ideal basis in a polynomial ring can be converted to another, do we have a bound for the necessary coefficient degrees of an inverse conversion?*

— 
*Edit: In the original question, $\beta$ was erroneously not allowed to depend on the maximal degrees of the bases.*

Comment: Is a basis of an ideal the same as a generating system?

Comment: Yes, the term “basis” and “generating system” are used interchangeably for ideals. (Which could honestly be confusing as an ideal must not be free and admit a basis in the module-theoretic sense.)

Comment: Then shouldn't be $I = (f_1 = X, f_2 = X^r) = (g = X)$ be a counterexample? We can write $g = 1 \cdot f_1$, so $d = 0$ is possible. But $f_2$ can only expressed via $g$ as $X^{r-1}$. The degree $r-1$ is unbounded.

Comment: To your comment above: Not every ideal in a polynomial ring is free as a module. Take $(X,Y)$ in $K[X,Y]$. It cannot be generated by one polynomial, but any two polynomials $f, g$ fulfill $gf - fg = 0$, so they are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks, Tzimmo. Of course that is a counterexample to my original question. I just realised I made a mistake in stating the question: the bound $\beta$ is supposed to depend not on the number of generators but on their maximal degree. My bad, I will edit the question.

If this is allowed, then we could bound $\beta = r-1$ in terms of the degree of $f_2$.

To the freeness of ideals: You may have just missed the little “not” in my first answer. I exactly meant that being a basis of an ideal does not mean that one has a module-theoretic basis (as this does not exist in general).

Comment: Whoops, I did indeed miss the "not". Sorry.

Comment: Here is a restatement in linear algebra terms, i.e. matrices over $R := K[X]$. Let $F := \begin{bmatrix} f_1 & \ldots & f_m \end{bmatrix}^t$, $S := \begin{bmatrix} s_{ij} \end{bmatrix}$ be given (which are $m \times 1$ and $n \times m$ matrices over $R$ respectively). Then your question is: assuming that a solution $T \in R^{m \times n}$ to $(I_m - TS)F = 0$ exists, can one bound $\deg T (:= \max \deg(t_{ij}))$ in terms of $\deg S, \deg F$?

Comment: From this one gets e.g. an obviously necessary (but not sufficient) condition, namely $\det(I_m - TS) = 0$

Comment: An affirmative answer in a special case: suppose WLOG $m \le n$, and $S = P\begin{bmatrix} I_m \\ A \end{bmatrix}Q$ for some $P, Q, A$ over $R$ with $P, Q$ invertible (so that $\det P, \det Q \in K^\times$ are nonzero scalars). Then $T := Q^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} I_m & 0 \end{bmatrix} P^{-1}$ is a solution, and here one can explicitly bound $\deg T$, since $\deg P^{-1} = \deg \operatorname{adj}(P) \le (n-1) \deg P$ (where $\operatorname{adj}$ is the classical adjugate, and similarly for $\deg Q^{-1}$)